# org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils in python

Tags: java, python, apache, apache-commons

is there any python module or code that implements the org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml ?

exactly the same as in http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml(java.lang.String)

i googled around but could only find the cgi.escape function that doesn't do the same thing.

thanks in advance, sorry for the english :D

Comment: found the solution in
http://www.peterbe.com/plog/html-entity-fixer

Comment: i've found something that work in peterbe.com/plog/html-entity-fixer

Answer (score 1):

This is for XML and not for HTML, but it might fit your needs: [Escaping XML](http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingXml)

```
>>> from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
>>>
>>> escape("< & >")
'&lt; &amp; &gt;'
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work...

the good thing is that i've found something that work in http://www.peterbe.com/plog/html-entity-fixer

thanks for the help